# C# Queue - out of memory

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, queue

I'm trying to make a minesweeper game in which I have made this method for flooding unknown tiles iteratively using Queue collection

```
private void FloodIterative(Tile tile)
{
    Queue<Tile> queue = new Queue<Tile>();
    queue.Enqueue(tile);

    while (queue.Count != 0)
    {
        Tile b = queue.Dequeue();

        if (b.isDiscovered) continue;
        if (b.type == Tile.Type.Mine || b.type == Bunka.Type.Invalid) continue;

        b.isDiscovered = true;
        state[b.position.x, b.position.y] = b;

        if (b.type == Bunka.Type.Empty)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x - 1, b.position.y));
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x + 1, b.position.y));
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x, b.position.y - 1));
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x, b.position.y + 1));
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x - 1, b.position.y - 1));
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x + 1, b.position.y + 1));
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x + 1, b.position.y - 1));
            queue.Enqueue(GetBunka(b.position.x - 1, b.position.y + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

This method works well but only for a limited amount of unexplored tiles. If the tile number gets too big my unity engine outputs:

*OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory*

*System.Collections.Generic.Queue 1[T].SetCapacity (System.Int32 capacity) (at <5a2009c85b134970925993880e2ecb2e>:0)
System.Collections.Generic.Queue 1[T].Enqueue (T item) (at <5a2009c85b134970925993880e2ecb2e>:0)*

Is there any solution to this? Is it possible that I need to deallocate memory manually?
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How much RAM is that `Queue` using and do you really need it all in-memory? The code makes it seem like there's potentially an endless loop that keeps filling up the queue. What is the code actually doing?

Comment: Normally it uses about 0.5GB and on peak (i click on a tile) 5GB but then the error comes in. The code is iteratively trying to uncover tiles that are not mines so it just uncovers all tiles that are not mines until it comes to a mine in which case it will not try to uncover it.

Comment: But how do you make sure the loop doesn't run forever?

Comment: Ehm there is a finite amount of tiles on the board?

Comment: Is there any reason to `Enqueue` a tile whose type is `Mine` or `Invalid`, or whose `isDiscovered` is set to `true`? Looks like every single tile is getting added... several times? Each `Enqueue` that you do for the original tile will add the original tile back onto the `Queue`, for example. Sure, you'll just continue when you encounter it again but... that's a lot of extra items on the queue.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem because `GetBunka` is undefined. Please edit the question to include a [mre]. Also - are you sure you are modifying the same values that `GetBunka` returns? Is `Tile` a `struct`? Your [mre] should include a sufficient definition for `Tile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers (0.5GB and 5GB) you mention makes me worried there's some other issue hiding around than what @joshua-robinson pointed out. If we pretend you have a grid of 100x100 and your current approach potentially adds every `Tile` 8 times to the queue it means `5GB / (100 * 100 * 8) == 65kB` per tile. That is **a lot** of memory for a single `Tile` - and this is assuming `GetBunka` instantiates a new `Tile` object instead of reusing the same `Tile` object on a given position. If the grid you have tested with is smaller, the amount of memory per `Tile` is even higher.

Without knowing the contents of `Tile` I would assume it should take up far less than 1kB.

---

But to address the matter at hand, we can use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) to keep track of the tiles we've already looked at to avoid adding those to the queue more than once.

```
private void FloodIterative(Tile tile)
{
    Queue<Tile> queue = new Queue<Tile>();
    queue.Enqueue(tile);

    // Tiles we have had a peak at
    // I.e. they were added to the queue at some point
    var tilesPeakedAt = new HashSet<Tile>(queue);

    while (queue.Count != 0)
    {
        Tile b = queue.Dequeue();

        if (b.isDiscovered) continue;
        if (b.type == Tile.Type.Mine || b.type == Bunka.Type.Invalid) continue;

        b.isDiscovered = true;
        state[b.position.x, b.position.y] = b;

        if (b.type == Bunka.Type.Empty)
        {
            var tilesToCheck = GetAllNeighbors(b)
                .Where(t => !tilesPeakedAt.Contains(t));
            foreach (var t in tilesToCheck)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(t);
                tilesPeakedAt.Add(t);
            }
        }
    }
}

private Tile[] GetAllNeighbors(Tile b) // Position as input would be enough
{
    return new []
    {
        GetBunka(b.position.x - 1, b.position.y)
        GetBunka(b.position.x + 1, b.position.y)
        GetBunka(b.position.x, b.position.y - 1)
        GetBunka(b.position.x, b.position.y + 1)
        GetBunka(b.position.x - 1, b.position.y - 1)
        GetBunka(b.position.x + 1, b.position.y + 1)
        GetBunka(b.position.x + 1, b.position.y - 1)
        GetBunka(b.position.x - 1, b.position.y + 1)
    };
}
```

This should lower the number of tiles put into the queue by up to a factor of 8.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippit from my minesweeper game I made a while back.

It helps to know how many mines surround a given tile.  This can be set during initial construction of the grid.

```
private void RevealEmptyAdjacentTiles(Point point)
{
    // Create a list to store the next tiles we need to check 
    //
    var nextTilesToCheck = new List<Tile>();

    // Loop through the adjacent tiles that are not yet revealed
    //
    foreach (var tile in GetAdjacentUnrevealedTiles(point))
    {
        // Make sure this tile is not a mine
        //
        if (!tile.IsMine)
        {
            // Reveal the tile
            //
            tile.Reveal();

            // We also want to check this tiles adjacent unrevealed tiles, add it to our list for checking after this loop completes
            //
            nextTilesToCheck.Add(tile);
        }
    }

    // Loop through all the new tiles we need to check
    //
    foreach (var adjacentTile in nextTilesToCheck)
    {
        // If there are no surrounding mines, lets run this function again for this coordinate
        //
        if (adjacentTile.SurroundingMinesCount == 0)
        {
            // Recursion
            //
            RevealEmptyAdjacentTiles(adjacentTile.Coordinate);
        }
    }
}
```

We are only concerned with tiles that have not yet been revealed.  When checking those unrevealed neighbor tiles, we reveal the tile (unless it is a mine), and subsequently those tiles will never need to be checked again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you queue 8 items for each one taken out AND you queue duplicates. Before placing item on queue check if it is not already there.

Comment: And how do you suppose I should do that? Is there a special data structure that implements this idea?

Comment: That's separate question: how. That depends on many factors. Dirty hack would be to use HashSet if processing order does not matter. But it really depends how Tile is coded/compared. Dirty solution  would be to simply check if queue has such item already, but that would do a lot of checking and with a lot of elements might be slow. Go search internet for some flood fill algorithms where some smart people can suggest tuned structures for the work.

Comment: @WojciechGebczyk Which issues do you see with `HashSet`? I'm wondering why you think of it as a "dirty hack"

Comment: Just a few from top of my head:

## if comparison of tile is not using only (x,y), then it might not work and custom comparer should be used

## if there is A LOT of tiles/cells, then resizing might hurt perf

## you will be doing a lot of add and remove from HashSet - in some case that might to be harsh for perf

## in some cases simple bool[,] array where you keep "things added" might be better idea if you thing you will visit significant amount of tiles/cels

etc

Comment: Fair enough, though I don't agree that it makes it a dirty hack. A `bool[,]` is practically the same, just a different data type that might help squeeze a little more performance out. But I guess it's up to the specific situation and preference.